# Which design to choose in this case?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am designing a database for a video game. I have some data structures like `{x, y, z, dimension}` used across multiple tables.

For instance :

*Table* `player_death`

```
id: int
player_id: int
death_x: int
death_y: int
death_z: int
death_dimension: int
```

Since `{x, y, z, dimension}` represents a geographic vector in the video game, a lot of table contain those columns. My question is : should I create a table named `vector` containing a pool of all the vectors used in my tables (and then use reference to them) or should I keep adding `{x, y, z, dimension}` columns to each table using a vector ? What is the best practice ? I am a beginner in database design, sorry if the question sounds stupid.

Comment: What will the information in this type of table be used for? If you're going to query it frequently, it may make sense to keep it denormalized in some way.

Comment: What rdbms?  Are you just storing those vectors or will you need to do calculations on then in the db?

Comment: @Jon Seigel, yes I'm going to query it (them) frequently and I'm using MySQL, only for storing them.

Comment: Actually, I feel a little bit strange to repeat those columns all over my database because I'm a developer and I learnt to never repeat myself (DRY principle). Is this relevant in database designs ?

Comment: Yes, it's very relevant. Keeping the vectors in a separate table is part of a process called normalization, which is a best practice. However, sometimes for maximum performance, the rules need to be broken (selectively). Usually one starts with a normalized design, and then denormalizes selected areas as a last resort. I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to say what options are available, so I'll bow out at this point.

Comment: How many different combinations of `x, y, z, dimension` are there? How likely is it that you'll be recording more than one value against a given combination?

Comment: @Chris Saxon there are theoretically about (2^86)*~10 different combinations. But it's very likely that I will have at least two identical combinations of `x, y, z, dimension`. I would estimate that two identical vectors should appear every ~1000 records.

Comment: @Jon Seigel, thank you very much! I didn't know about the concept of normalization. I just read an article about it and it answers to my question! Maybe you should post your comment as a post so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
should I create a table named vector containing a pool of all the vectors used in my tables?
```

No

Creating such a table and referencing to it would only be helpful If you know that many, many players are going to die in the same spot. Assuming that death of players will be in random locations, creating another table will not help, and your select queries will have to carry an unnecessary overhead of joins. If your queries will mainly look like this, then this option is best for you :

```
SELECT * FROM player_death WHERE player_id = <playerid>
```

On the other hand, if your game largely depended on coordinates of places rather than death places of players, creating another table would have been relevant. For example, if you want to spawn monsters only where players have died , or if you have to paint the death place red, and some other place yellow and rest all green, these all are relevant to  on position in the map, not death place of players, and it'd be better to have a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Two to the power eighty-six records?! This is about fifteen orders of magnitude larger than any table I've ever worked with - I doubt even Google or Facebook have tables close to this size! Based on this alone, I'd say that having a lookup table of all the possible values is a nonsense.

Regarding normalization: I believe your table is already fully normalised (to 5NF), though I think you're missing `time_of_death` from your (candidate) key. The co-ordinates of death are than all dependent on a given player and their time of death (`player_id, time_of_death`). so you don't need to "normalize" these into another table.

It can be useful to have lookup tables when you're fully normalized though to help with the following:

- It allows you to use referential integrity to restrict the values for given column(s)
- Lookup tables are (usually) significantly smaller than the tables referencing them. Querying these to provide drop-downs etc. to users can be significantly more efficient than getting a distinct list of values from the child table.
- You think it's likely you'll be adding attributes to the lookup table in the future (e.g. business requirements planned for a future release)

I doubt any of these apply in your case though, so I don't see how a lookup table will help you.